# java : How can I cast Date from "Thu May 01 00:00:00 WEST 2014 " to "2014-01-05 00:00:00.0"

Tags: java, date, datetime

How can I want to  cast Date from "Thu May 01 00:00:00 WEST 2014 " to "2014-01-05 00:00:00.0"

I try with this code :

```
SimpleDateFormat toFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
        String dateStr = getDtdebut().toString();
        Date date = new Date();
        try {
            date = toFormat.parse(dateStr);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but i have this error :

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu May 01 00:00:00 WEST 2014"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
at ensa.pfe.action.GestionOperations.filtre(GestionOperations.java:386)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:440)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:279)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
..........
```

Comment: why exactly are you first casting it to a String?

Comment: Because i don't know if it was another way to do this casting

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29

Comment: afaik you're not supposed to cast it at all, just apply a formatter on the date object you had

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.util.Date` is just a wrapper class around timestamp value (i.e. number of milliseconds since UNIX epoch). This object is in no way connected to any specific date format or even a calendar system.

What you need is just to format a date, not to convert it to string using some default formatter and then parsing it back to format independent object again. Use [`DateFormat#format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29).

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
System.out.println(format.format(getDtdebut()));
```